# Does zgrep reuse recently uncompressed files?

Tags: grep, optimization

I am calling `zgrep` over *.gz files in a for loop in one directory.

As the log files are huge (about 1GB each, and about 30 files), the command is taking a long time.

I see several uncompressed files in `/tmp` folder, which the zgrep is creating.

I would like to know, does `zgrep` reuse it's own uncompressed files? Or does it uncompress them each time (i.e. next iteration of for loop)?

The script does

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r request;
do
    zgrep $request */log.prefix.* | grep ..... <complex command>
read < /tmp/allRequestIds.txt
```

Any hints on optimizing the zgrep?

Comment: Why are you piping the result of `zgrep` to `grep`?

Comment: Does `zgrep` even create temporary files? I would think it can just pipe the uncompressed data to `grep`, without saving it.

Comment: @dr01 `zgrep` outputs 1000 lines for a request id, then I need to filter out specific lines, and later again just display the matched ouptut using `grep -o`

Comment: @mtk You can do all of this with a single call to `zgrep`.

Answer (score 2):

`zgrep PATTERN FILE` is essentially the same as `zcat FILE | grep PATTERN` or some variation thereof.  It will not reuse previously uncompressed files if you run it in a loop.

To speed up your processing, allow `zgrep` to read the patterns directly from the `/tmp/allRequestIds.txt` file:

```
zgrep -f /tmp/allRequestIds.txt */log.prefix.*
```

If you want fixed string pattern matching rather than regular expression matching, also use `-F`:

```
zgrep -F -f /tmp/allRequestIds.txt */log.prefix.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which has compatible syntax to `grep` and it's more powerful since it's written in [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(programming_language)) and it is built on top of [Rust's regex engine](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/regex) which uses finite automata, SIMD and aggressive literal optimizations to make searching very fast. Check the [detailed analysis here](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/).

Example usage:

```
rg -z "pattern" .
```

> `-z`/`--search-zip` Search in compressed files (`gz`, `bz2`, `xz`, and `lzma`).